# Scratch Org configuration gives error "SocialCustomerService is not a valid Features value"

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am creating a new scratch org with a configuration file to enable "SocialCustomerService" feature flag. But SFDX cli it not recognizing this feature flag. Getting an error "SocialCustomerService is not a valid Features value". "SocialCustomerService" is available as a feature flag in the link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

Feature section of scratch org configuration,
 "features": ["AuthorApex","LightningServiceConsole", "StateAndCountryPicklist", "SocialCustomerService"]

Answer (score 3):

SocialCustomerService is added in version 47 (Winter '20)
You need to specify in your configuration to use the preview version for your scratch org.

You can select the Salesforce version by adding release to your org configuration

```
{
   "orgName": "Dreamhouse",
   "edition": "Developer",
   "release": "Preview",
   "settings": {
     "orgPreferenceSettings": {
       "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
       "selfSetPasswordInApi": true,
       "s1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
     }
   }
}
```

Source: [Select the Salesforce Release for a Scratch Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_version_selection.htm)